# pyspark dataframe filtering doesn't really remove rows?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

My dataframe undergoes two consecutive filtering passes each using a boolean-valued UDF. The first filtering removes all rows whose columns are not present as keys in some broadcast dictionary. The second filtering imposes thresholds on values that this dictionary associates with the present keys.

If I display the result after just the first filtering, the row with 'c' is not in it, as expected. However, attempts to display the result of the second filtering lead to a KeyError exception for u'c'

```py
sc = SparkContext()
ss = SparkSession(sc)

mydict={ "a" : 4, "b" : 6 }
mydict_bc = sc.broadcast(mydict)

udf_indict=func.udf( lambda x: x in mydict_bc.value, BooleanType() )
udf_bigenough=func.udf( lambda x: mydict_bc.value[x] > 5, BooleanType() )

df=ss.createDataFrame([ "a", "b", "c" ], StringType() ).toDF("name")
df1 = df.where( udf_indict('name') )
df1.show()

    +----+                                                                          
    |name|
    +----+
    |   a|
    |   b|
    +----+

df1.where( udf_bigenough('name') ).show()

KeyError: u'c'
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    ...
```

I guess this has something to do with delayed execution and internal optimization, but is this really an expected behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> My dataframe undergoes two consecutive filtering passes

is incorrect assumption. Unlike `RDD`, where all transformations are WYSIWYG, SQL API is purely declarative. It explains what has to be done, but not how. Optimizer can rearrange all elements as it see fit.

Using nondeterministic variant will disable optimizations:

```
df1 = df.where( udf_indict.asNondeterministic()('name'))
df1.where( udf_bigenough.asNondeterministic()('name') ).show()
```

but you should really handle exceptions

```
@udf(BooleanType())
   def udf_bigenough(x):
      try:
          return mydict_bc.get(x) > 5
      except TypeError:
          pass
```

or better, not use `udf`.